# bundler: command not found: puma on Heroku deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Ruby newbie here, so please forgive me if this is a stupid question with an easy fix.

I'm working through Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial (6th edition), but I'm encountering the following error when I try to run the app on Heroku:
`bundler: command not found: puma`

I can run the app locally just fine (at this point it's basically just a "hello, world!" app), but when I look at my Heroku logs, I see:

```
    2021-12-30T22:16:19.744803+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
    2021-12-30T22:16:21.801584+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: command not found: puma
    2021-12-30T22:16:21.801624+00:00 app[web.1]: Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
    2021-12-30T22:16:22.047341+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2021-12-30T22:16:22.101982+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2021-12-30T22:16:22.106731+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2021-12-30T22:16:25.682923+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
    2021-12-30T22:16:26.810275+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: command not found: puma
    2021-12-30T22:16:26.810296+00:00 app[web.1]: Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
    2021-12-30T22:16:26.964600+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
    2021-12-30T22:16:27.024801+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I've copied all relevant files from [Hartl's GitHub page](https://github.com/mhartl/sample_app_6th_ed).  Those files are:

Gemfile:

```
gem 'active_storage_validations', '0.8.9'
gem 'bcrypt',                     '3.1.13'
gem 'faker',                      '2.11.0'
gem 'will_paginate',              '3.3.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate',    '1.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',             '3.4.1'
gem 'puma',                       '5.3.1'
gem 'sass-rails',                 '6.0.0'
gem 'webpacker',                  '5.4.0'
gem 'turbolinks',                 '5.2.1'
gem 'jbuilder',                   '2.10.0'
gem 'bootsnap',                   '1.7.2', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.4.2'
  gem 'byebug',  '11.1.3', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',        '4.1.0'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '2.3.1'
  gem 'listen',             '3.4.1'
  gem 'spring',             '2.1.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara',                 '3.35.3'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver',       '3.142.7'
  gem 'webdrivers',               '4.6.0'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.5'
  gem 'minitest',                 '5.11.3'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.3.8'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.16.2'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.6'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',         '1.2.3'
  gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '1.87.0', require: false
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
# Uncomment the following line if you're running Rails
# on a native Windows system:
# gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

config/puma.rb:

```
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }
threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { ENV['RACK_ENV'] || "development" }
pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }
workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { 2 }
preload_app!
plugin :tmp_restart
```

When I run `heroku run gem list puma` I get nothing, even though puma is in my Gemfile.  I've looked through a bunch of posts with this error, but none of them had a solution that seemed to work for my specific problem

**EDIT**

Adding Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.1.4.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.1.4.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.1)
      activejob (= 6.1.4.1)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4.1)
      activestorage (= 6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.1.4.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.1)
      actionview (= 6.1.4.1)
      activejob (= 6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.1.4.1)
      actionview (= 6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.9)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.1.4.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.1)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4.1)
      activestorage (= 6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    active_storage_validations (0.8.9)
      rails (>= 5.2.0)
    activejob (6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
    activerecord (6.1.4.1)
      activemodel (= 6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
    activestorage (6.1.4.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.1)
      activejob (= 6.1.4.1)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
      marcel (~> 1.0.0)
      mini_mime (>= 1.1.0)
    activesupport (6.1.4.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.3)
    addressable (2.8.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    ansi (1.5.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (10.4.0.0)
      execjs (~> 2)
    aws-eventstream (1.2.0)
    aws-partitions (1.543.0)
    aws-sdk-core (3.125.0)
      aws-eventstream (~> 1, >= 1.0.2)
      aws-partitions (~> 1, >= 1.525.0)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
      jmespath (~> 1.0)
    aws-sdk-kms (1.53.0)
      aws-sdk-core (~> 3, >= 3.125.0)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
    aws-sdk-s3 (1.87.0)
      aws-sdk-core (~> 3, >= 3.109.0)
      aws-sdk-kms (~> 1)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.1)
    aws-sigv4 (1.4.0)
      aws-eventstream (~> 1, >= 1.0.2)
    bcrypt (3.1.13)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.7.2)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    bootstrap-sass (3.4.1)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1)
      sassc (>= 2.0.0)
    bootstrap-will_paginate (1.0.0)
      will_paginate
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    capybara (3.35.3)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    coderay (1.1.3)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.9)
    crass (1.0.6)
    erubi (1.10.0)
    execjs (2.8.1)
    faker (2.11.0)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
    ffi (1.15.4)
    formatador (0.3.0)
    globalid (1.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
    guard (2.16.2)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      lumberjack (>= 1.0.12, < 2.0)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      notiffany (~> 0.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-compat (1.2.1)
    guard-minitest (2.4.6)
      guard-compat (~> 1.2)
      minitest (>= 3.0)
    i18n (1.8.11)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    image_processing (1.9.3)
      mini_magick (>= 4.9.5, < 5)
      ruby-vips (>= 2.0.13, < 3)
    jbuilder (2.10.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    jmespath (1.4.0)
    listen (3.4.1)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    loofah (2.13.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    lumberjack (1.2.8)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (1.0.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mini_magick (4.9.5)
    mini_mime (1.1.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.6.1)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    minitest-reporters (1.3.8)
      ansi
      builder
      minitest (>= 5.0)
      ruby-progressbar
    msgpack (1.4.2)
    nenv (0.3.0)
    nio4r (2.5.8)
    nokogiri (1.12.5)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.6.1)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    notiffany (0.1.3)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
    pg (1.2.3)
    pry (0.14.1)
      coderay (~> 1.1)
      method_source (~> 1.0)
    public_suffix (4.0.6)
    puma (5.3.1)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.6.0)
    rack (2.2.3)
    rack-mini-profiler (2.3.1)
      rack (>= 1.2.0)
    rack-proxy (0.7.0)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (6.1.4.1)
      actioncable (= 6.1.4.1)
      actionmailbox (= 6.1.4.1)
      actionmailer (= 6.1.4.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.1)
      actiontext (= 6.1.4.1)
      actionview (= 6.1.4.1)
      activejob (= 6.1.4.1)
      activemodel (= 6.1.4.1)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4.1)
      activestorage (= 6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 6.1.4.1)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-controller-testing (1.0.5)
      actionpack (>= 5.0.1.rc1)
      actionview (>= 5.0.1.rc1)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.1.rc1)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.2)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (6.1.4.1)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.1)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.1)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.13)
      thor (~> 1.0)
    rake (13.0.6)
    rb-fsevent (0.11.0)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    regexp_parser (2.2.0)
    ruby-progressbar (1.11.0)
    ruby-vips (2.1.4)
      ffi (~> 1.12)
    rubyzip (2.3.2)
    sass-rails (6.0.0)
      sassc-rails (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
    sassc (2.4.0)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    semantic_range (3.0.0)
    shellany (0.0.1)
    spring (2.1.1)
    sprockets (4.0.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.4.2)
    thor (1.1.0)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (2.0.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    web-console (4.1.0)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (4.6.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 3.0, < 4.0)
    webpacker (5.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 5.2)
      semantic_range (>= 2.3.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    will_paginate (3.3.0)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.5.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  active_storage_validations (= 0.8.9)
  aws-sdk-s3 (= 1.87.0)
  bcrypt (= 3.1.13)
  bootsnap (= 1.7.2)
  bootstrap-sass (= 3.4.1)
  bootstrap-will_paginate (= 1.0.0)
  byebug (= 11.1.3)
  capybara (= 3.35.3)
  faker (= 2.11.0)
  guard (= 2.16.2)
  guard-minitest (= 2.4.6)
  image_processing (= 1.9.3)
  jbuilder (= 2.10.0)
  listen (= 3.4.1)
  mini_magick (= 4.9.5)
  minitest (= 5.11.3)
  minitest-reporters (= 1.3.8)
  pg (= 1.2.3)
  puma (= 5.3.1)
  rack-mini-profiler (= 2.3.1)
  rails (= 6.1.4.1)
  rails-controller-testing (= 1.0.5)
  sass-rails (= 6.0.0)
  selenium-webdriver (= 3.142.7)
  spring (= 2.1.1)
  sqlite3 (= 1.4.2)
  turbolinks (= 5.2.1)
  web-console (= 4.1.0)
  webdrivers (= 4.6.0)
  webpacker (= 5.4.0)
  will_paginate (= 3.3.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   2.1.4
```

Comment: Have you run `bundle install` before deploying to Heroku? Your `Gemfile.lock` might be missing `puma`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to include that, but yeah, I've run ```bundle install``` a bunch of times.  I'll post my Gemfile.lock, but puma is in there

Comment: This smells like a versioning issue between multiple installed bundler and/or rubygems.